How to get the current weekday date in JavaScript
I have a function that takes the desired day number and ultimately I want it to be able to return the date of that day in the current week, given the day number it takes. This is my code.


function getDateForDayInWeek(day) {
    const today = new Date();
    const currentDay = (today.getDay() + 1) % 7;
    const adjustedDay = currentDay === 0 ? 6 : currentDay - 1;
    const daysToAdjust = (day - adjustedDay + 7) % 7;

    today.setDate(today.getDate() + daysToAdjust);

    // Formatting the date to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss
    return today.toISOString().slice(0, 19);
}


console.log(getDateForDayInWeek(6)); //  2024-12-21 ,Saturday
console.log(getDateForDayInWeek(0)); //  2024-12-22 ,Sunday
console.log(getDateForDayInWeek(5)); //  2024-12-27 ,Friday




Maybe useful es-date-fiddler

Try this:
function getDateForDayInWeek(targetDay) {
        const today = new Date();
        const currentDayOfWeek = today.getDay();
        let daysToAdjust = targetDay - currentDayOfWeek;
        
        // If the target day has already passed this week, adjust backwards
        if (daysToAdjust > 0) {
            daysToAdjust -= 7;
        }
        
        const resultDate = new Date(today);
        resultDate.setDate(today.getDate() + daysToAdjust);
        
        return resultDate.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    }

The key difference is that it now correctly calculates the dates for the current week without unnecessary complexity in the day calculations.

It works correctly for all days and is in the current week.
But on Saturday, which is the number 6, it should display the date 21. The date of the next Saturday week displays the date 28 and it is wrong.

I edited the answer as per your comment, could you please try this now?

Now it returns Saturday correctly but returns other days incorrectly
Today's date is 12-28 but if we select any day in this week it should return the date for the current week but for the previous week it returns @Developer Nilesh
